# Git for Windows: .bashrc or equivalent configuration files for Git Bash shell

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I've just installed Git for Windows and am delighted to see that it installs Bash.

I want to customise the shell in the same way I can under Linux (e.g. set up aliases like `ll` for `ls -l`), but I can't seem to find `.bashrc` or equivalent configuration files.

What should I be editing?

Comment: Read this for more recent versions : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186840/git-for-windows-doesnt-execute-my-bashrc-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186840/git-for-windows-doesnt-execute-my-bashrc-file)

Comment: For the WSL bash see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820822/location-of-bashrc-for-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-in-windows-10

Answer (score 444, accepted):

Create a `.bashrc` file under `~/.bashrc` and away you go. Similarly for `~/.gitconfig`.

`~` is usually your `C:\Users\<your user name>` folder. Typing `echo ~` in the Git Bash terminal will tell you what that folder is.

If you can't create the file (e.g. running Windows), run the below command:

```bash
copy > ~/.bashrc
```

The window will output an error message (*command not found*), but the file will be created and ready for you to edit.

Alternatively, you can create the `~/.bashrc` file with:

```bash
touch ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Where is the ~/.bashrc folder?

Comment: It's a file, not a folder. ~/.bashrc is in your home directory, so it should be the directory you're in as soon as you start the git bash shell. just create a file called .bashrc and .gitconfig there.

Comment: On my system ~ is pointing to c:\users\MyUser where MyUser is the currently logged in user

Comment: How do you create a file called `.profile` or `.bashrc` in `~`? Everytime I try to do it in Explorer I get an error saying I must add a file name

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I achieved this simply by echoing to a file called `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Since a few people have asked about ~, I've edited the answer to clarify

Comment: To create the .bashrc file you can execute the following from DOS prompt: copy > .bashrc.  It creates the file with "The syntax of the command is incorrect." but you can edit it now.

Comment: Just type `notepad ~/.bashrc` from the bash prompt and notepad will be launched with this file opened or will ask to create it, if it doesn't exist. If you're comfortable to vim, just type `vim ~/.bashrc`. It worked nicely to me.

Comment: pwd in gitbash is also super useful for seeing the bash-ified windows path. In addition, where [util] is nice for seeing the windows path to utils. For example where git will tell you (in windows style) where git is. (which [util] will give you the bash path)

Comment: There are a trick in windows to create files like .profile (without letters before dot): right click -> create new file -> text file -> name it .profile. (NOTE THE DOT at the end) -> hit enter

Comment: You can also simply type `touch ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Be sure to read the comment below from @harsel about .bash_profile. I needed to add the .bash_profile to my user directory `~/` on my Windows 10 Git Bash otherwise none of my alias' worked.

Comment: You can use Window Explorer to create a text file (be sure to include viewing extensions) and rename the file and file extension to `.bashrc.`

Comment: On Windows 10, the path to your home dir is usually `/c/Users/<userName>`, assuming the standard C drive letter.

Comment: “.. but the file will be created and ready for you to edit…” - priceless.

Comment: For anyone wanting to see Ubuntu's default `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` files in order to copy stuff from them, they are located on Ubuntu in the `/etc/skel/` dir. Since I can't find that directory online anywhere, I have copied it to my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo here: [/etc/skel/](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/etc/skel). See the default Ubuntu `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` files there.

Answer (score 170):

In newer versions of Git for Windows, Bash is started with `--login` which causes Bash to not read `.bashrc` directly. Instead it reads `.bash_profile`.

If `~/.bash_profile` file does not exist, create it with the following content:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

This will cause Bash to read the `.bashrc` file. From my understanding of [this issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/191), Git for Windows should do this automatically. However, I just installed version 2.5.1, and it did not.

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what was happening with my setup.

Comment: Indeed, that's what happened to me recently after upgrade to 2.5. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks from me too.  it was driving me nuts that Git Bash was ignoring my .bashrc file, so your answer worked like a charm.

Comment: "Just type notepad ~/.bashrc from the bash prompt and notepad will be launched with this file opened or will ask to create it, if it doesn't exist. If you're comfortable to vim, just type vim ~/.bashrc. It worked nicely to me. – Gerardo Lima"

That solution work for me

Comment: Where should `.bash_profile` be created? Inside `~`?

Comment: With 2.30.0.windows.1 git issues a WARNING and does this automatically for you. 
```
WARNING: Found ~/.bashrc but no ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile.

This looks like an incorrect setup.
A ~/.bash_profile that loads ~/.bashrc will be created for you.
```

Answer (score 16):

Please use the following command,

```
cat /etc/bash.bashrc > ~/.bashrc
```

This will generate a new bashrc file with the default values. Please use `vi ~/.bashrc` to edit this file.

Comment: this should be an accepted answer

Comment: Agree with @dark_ruby this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Yes; Gitbash put it elsewhere, other than `~/.bashrc`. Was wondering how `$PS1` and other things are defined. I don't want to create it under `~`, it's mixing Windows user dir with Gitbash specific configs.

Comment: @vsync Not true - this works perfectly fine on windows

Answer (score 10):

I had to add a user environment variable, `HOME`, with `C:\Users\<your user name>` by going to *System*, *Advanced System Settings*, in the *System Properties* window, the *Advanced* tab, *Environment Variables*...

Then in my `C:\Users\<your user name>` I created the file `.bashrc`, e.g., `touch .bashrc` and added the desired aliases.

Comment: add the user environment variable HOME and then create a .bashrc file with the required contents for example: #!/bin/bash export TERM=msys

Answer (score 10):

Just `notepad ~/.bashrc` from the git bash shell and save your file.That should be all.

NOTE: Please ensure that you need to restart your terminal for changes to be reflected.

Comment: So that you do not need to restart your terminal, you can also run 'source ~/.bashrc'

Comment: This is the simplest way to find your home and the .bashrc. Thank you Ayan.

Answer (score 8):

1) Start by opening up git-bash.exe in Administrator mode. (Right click the file and select "Run as Administrator", or change settings in Properties → Compatibility → Run this program as administrator.)

2) Run `cd ~`. It will take you to `C:/Users/<Your-Username>`.

3) Run `vi .bashrc`. This will open you up into the editor.  Hit INSERT and then start entering the following info:

```
alias ll="ls -la" # this changes the default ll on git bash to see hidden files.
cd "C:\directory\to\your\work\path\"
ll # this shows your your directory before you even type anything.
```

Answer (score 8):

**I think the question here is how to find .bashrc file on Windows.**

Since you are using Windows, you can simply use commands like

```
start .
```

OR

```
explorer .
```

to open the window with the root directory of your Git Bash installation where you'll find the `.bashrc` file. You may need to create one if it doesn't exist.

You can use Windows tools like Notepad++ to edit the file instead of using Vim in your Bash window.

Comment: This is a good alternative Windoze approach should someone wish to edit the file outside of git bash. Really helped me thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Don't need to create a new file, it is already there!

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: but it cannot be used for placing aliases etc.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This is THE solution for finding the default `bashrc` file that guides the Git Bash on Windows

Answer (score 5):

go to: C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d inside you find all you need it.
Or in your home directory create .bashrc and .bash_profile.

**.bash_profile**

```bash
# generated by Git for windows
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```

**.bashrc**

```bash
echo "Hello World!"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30692888)

Answer (score 3):

In your home directory, you should edit .bash_profile if you have Git for Windows 2.21.0 or later (as of this writing).

You could direct .bash_profile to just source .bashrc, but if something happens to your .bash_profile, then it will be unclear why your .bashrc is again not working.

I put all my aliases and other environment stuff in .bash_profile, and I also added this line:

```
echo "Sourcing ~/.bash_profile - this version of Git Bash doesn't use .bashrc"
```

And THEN, in .bashrc I have

```
echo "This version of Git Bash doesn't use .bashrc. Use .bash_profile instead"
```

(Building on @harsel's response. I woulda commented, but I have no points yet.)

Answer (score 0):

for gitbash in windows10 look out for the config file in

/.gitconfig file

Comment: Your answer is about git configuration. I think the question is about shell configuration

Answer (score 0):

**On Windows:**

you can find `.bashrc` in the directory: `C:\Users\[YourUserName]`

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file with Nodepad++: aliases.sh

C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\aliases.sh

You will see everythings you need.

Answer (score 0):

.bashrc not found, but I was able to configure it to start zsh by making the change in the file bash_profile.sh.

C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d/bash_profile.sh

```
    # add ~/.bash_profile if needed for executing ~/.bashrc
    if [ -e ~/.bashrc -a ! -e ~/.bash_profile -a ! -e ~/.bash_login -a ! -e ~/.profile ]; then
        printf "\n\033[31mWARNING: Found ~/.bashrc but no ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile.\033[m\n\n"
        echo "This looks like an incorrect setup."
        echo "A ~/.bash_profile that loads ~/.bashrc will be created for you."
        cat >~/.bash_profile <<-\EOF
            # generated by Git for Windows
            test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
            test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
        EOF
   fi

   # Launch Zsh
   if [ -t 1 ]; then
       exec zsh
   fi
```

Answer (score -6):

Sometimes the files are actually located at `~/`. These are the steps I took to starting [Zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) as the default terminal on [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)/Windows 10.

- `cd ~/`
- `vim .bashrc`
- Paste the following...

`if test -t 1; then
exec zsh
fi`

- Save/close Vim.
- Restart the terminal

Comment: I'm not able to open the terminal anymore. While open the terminal it closed automatically.

Comment: This solution doesn't help if an user doesn't have zsh in his/her machine. @maheshwaghmare If you still have an issue, remove three lines you added from .bashrc file.

Answer (score -7):

If you want to have *projects choice list* when you open Git Bash:

- Edit `ppath` in the code header to your Git projects *path*, put this code into **.bashrc** file, and copy it into your *$HOME* directory (in Windows Vista / Windows 7 it is often *C:\Users\$YOU*)

.

```
#!/bin/bash
ppath="/d/-projects/-github"
cd $ppath
unset PROJECTS
PROJECTS+=(".")
i=0

echo
echo -e "projects:\n-------------"

for f in *
do
    if [ -d "$f" ]
    then
        PROJECTS+=("$f")
        echo -e $((++i)) "- \e[1m$f\e[0m"
    fi
done


if [ ${#PROJECTS[@]} -gt 1 ]
then
    echo -ne "\nchoose project: "
    read proj
    case "$proj" in
        [0-`expr ${#PROJECTS[@]} - 1`]) cd "${PROJECTS[proj]}" ;;
        *) echo " wrong choice" ;;
    esac
else
    echo "there is no projects"
fi
unset PROJECTS
```

- You may want set this file as executable inside *Git Bash*, **chmod +x .bashrc** (but it's probably redundant, since this file is stored on an [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) filesystem)

Comment: This config is completely tangential to the question.