# I see two versions of git bash, whether I open it bare or launch it from within git gui

Tags: git, windows-7

New to git, as you will suppose.

I installed git on windows (vista) Everything goes fine, except I get two slightly different versions of git bash:

1. Launch git bash from start menu
2. Launch git gui, then from within it, launch git bash

The first one has only 'git_bash' in the app title, the second has `MINGW32:c/gittest`. Both work well on my test repository, but the gui launched one echoes my directory changes, displays my windows username. The bare git bash simply works, but looks more basic.

So what is happening and how can I get the 'rich' git bash without previously having to launch the gui?

Comment: If you are more accustomed to the windows environment than unix, you should take a look at posh-git (http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/13/better-git-with-powershell.aspx/) and start using git in PowerShell instead of bash.

Comment: My I suggest either [sourcetree](http://sourcetreeapp.com) or [github for Windows](https://windows.github.com/) - both are free and excellent; they will also fix a lot of other Windows quirks (like line endings, for example).

Answer (score 1):

It simply is because `git-gui` will set the `PS1` variable from [`<yourGitForWindows>/etc/profile` file](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/etc/profile):

```
# non-printable characters must be enclosed inside \[ and \]
PS1='\[\033]0;$MSYSTEM:${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]' # set window title
PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'       # change color
PS1="$PS1"'\u@\h '             # user@host<space>
PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[33m\]'       # change color
PS1="$PS1"'\w'                 # current working directory
```

You can try and set that in a [`%HOME%/.bashrc` file](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/commit/a98a7a0)

See also "[Alter Git prompt on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10133606/6309)".