# How to change username and hostname for git bash on Windows?

Tags: git, git-bash

How can I change the username and hostname in git bash?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the Git username](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063493/changing-the-git-username)

Comment: That setting is customized in `PS1` in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or `.profile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set up user name in git:

```
# set the user name as global (user level) configuration
git config --global user.name "user name"
```

To change the bash prompt read those answers:

[Where exactly Git Bash for Windows' prompt is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689548/where-exactly-git-bash-for-windows-prompt-is-defined)
[Alter Git prompt on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133173/alter-git-prompt-on-windows)

The basic issue is the you will have to create user profile file like you do in Unix. In widows it will be placed under `%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\etc\profile` and you will set the `PS1` environment variable there.

Comment: The code snippet doesn't address the problem. That's just git configuration which is kinda irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

you have thre posibilities:

1. Systemwide change of that properties:

   > git config --system user.name "user5148540"
2. changes on Windows user level

   > git config --global user.name "user5148540"
3. Repository (Projekt Level) Level: for just a Projekt:

   > git config user.name "user5148540"

Answer (score -1):

1. For hostname, Change your  computer name from system properties of PC
2. For username change your account name( from which you log in)