# One GIT command to rule them all (gacp: git-add-commit-push)

Tags: git, bash, terminal, command, alias

I would really love a specialized git alias / bash function that can do the following.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "$MESSAGE"
git push origin master
```

All with a single command.

```
gacp
> My message
CONTENTS OF COMMIT
CONTENTS OF PUSH
```

Can this be done? Could someone share some sample code? Is there a native git function that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on linux, just write a shell script or create an alias

For example.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

set -x  # Output executed commands
set -e  # Make script fail as soon as one command fails

read MESSAGE

git add -A
git commit -m "$MESSAGE"
git push origin master
```

Comment: In addition, name it `git-foo`, put it somewhere in your `$PATH`, and then you can run it either as `git-foo` or `git foo`.

Comment: How, in linux / unix can you make a "console" type of interface. I hate adding quotes for the first argument and would love it if right after I typed the command there was a new line with some kind of identifier like `>` then this would be the message / argument.

Answer (score 1):

on my windows machine . i have set up this bashrc alias to make the entire process more simple.

- create / locate your .bashrc  -  [refer stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883760/git-for-windows-bashrc-or-equivalent-config-files-for-git-bash-shell)
- add the following line to file

  alias gacp='echo "enter commit message : " && read MSG && git add . && git commit -m "$MSG" && git push'
- reload .bashrc / close and reopen your shell
- now you can do the entire process with gacp command .

Answer (score 0):

The first two commands can be launch with :

```
git commit -a -m "$MESSAGE"
```

Then, you can check other commands :

```
git pull --rebase 
git rebase -i
```

**before** to do a git push.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the answer here: [git add, commit and push commands in one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595067/git-add-commit-and-push-commands-in-one/41366192#41366192)

You can try [gitu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-upload).

For the first time (node js has to be installed):

```
npm install -g git-upload
```

After that:

```
gitu COMMIT_MSG
```

To issue those three commands at once.

The good thing is that you **don't have to worry when you reinstall your system or when you want to do this on different computers and No file modification is needed.**
This also **work on different platforms** (not just Linux and Mac, but also Windows) just that you have to install `npm` and `nodejs` (`git` of course).