# javac command not found in Git Bash

Tags: windows, bash, path

I'm using Windows and Git Bash. Whenever I type a `javac` command in Git Bash, it comes back reading: `sh.exe":javac: command not found`.

I then have to type out `export PATH=$PATH:"/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/"` The `javac` command then works on the next line after I type the export PATH command in.

My question is, how do I get Git Bash to remember that export command so I don't have to type it out each time?

Comment: [off-topic] I recommend you to try https://cygwin.com/ as a command line tool. It's a NIX-shell tool for Windows.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `export PATH` command to .bashrc for Git Bash. Refer to this
[Git for Windows: .bashrc or equivalent config files for Git Bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883760/git-for-windows-bashrc-or-equivalent-config-files-for-git-bash-shell)

Edit: Adding code

```
copy > ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following line to the file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/"
```

Save the file. Restart Git Bash. Tada

Comment: On the current latest version of Windows10 the .bashrc file needs to be named .bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

Try physically adding that path to the system environment variables from the control panel.

Search for 'system environment variables' --> go into Environment Variables --> look for [Path] from System Variables --> Click to highlight [Path] and hit Edit.

Depending on your computer, you might see a list of paths added, or a long string of paths separated by semi-colons. Copy and paste your java bin location.