# Git for Windows doesn't execute my .bashrc file

Tags: windows, git, bash, windows-7

I've just installed Git for Windows 2.5.0 on Windows 7, and it appears that my `.bashrc` file is not being executed when I run Git Bash.

I created the file like so:

```
Administrator@HintTech-Dev MINGW64 /
$ pwd
/

Administrator@HintTech-Dev MINGW64 /
$ cd ~

Administrator@HintTech-Dev MINGW64 ~
$ pwd
/c/Users/Administrator

Administrator@HintTech-Dev MINGW64 ~
$ touch .bashrc

Administrator@HintTech-Dev MINGW64 ~
$ vi .bashrc

[... I insert the line "ZZZTESTVAR=234" (without the quotes) into the file in vim ...]

Administrator@HintTech-Dev MINGW64 ~
$ exit
```

Yet, when I next run Git Bash:

```
Administrator@HintTech-Dev MINGW64 /
$ set | grep ZZZ

Administrator@HintTech-Dev MINGW64 /
$ cat ~/.bashrc
ZZZTESTVAR=234

Administrator@HintTech-Dev MINGW64 /
$ ZZZTESTVAR=234

Administrator@HintTech-Dev MINGW64 /
$ set | grep ZZZ
ZZZTESTVAR=234

Administrator@HintTech-Dev MINGW64 /
$
```

Why isn't my `.bashrc` being run?  It seems to be in the right place and have the right permissions.

Comment: I am running Git bash version 1.9.5-preview20150319 and ran the exact same test you ran, but for me, it worked.  My `.bashrc` *was* run.  The variable *was* set.  Do you have a `.profile` or `.bash_profile` in the way?  These will stop `.bashrc` from being run.

Comment: Nope, I don't even have a `.profile` or `.bash_profile`.  But were you using Git for Windows 2.5.0?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

OK, I found out the problem.  Quite simply, the bash terminal used by the latest Git for Windows 2.5.0 (mintty) doesn't bother to read `.bashrc` - it reads `.bash_profile`.  So you can set up your environment in `.bash_profile` and/or put this code at the start to read `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]
then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: It's not mintty per se but how git-bash.exe starts it. Long discussion about it here which basically ends with the installer being changed to create a .bash_profile like you describe: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/191

Comment: Solution still works today May 2020 on windows 10 git bash

Answer (score 29):

Same thing happened to me when I upgraded to Git Bash 2.5.0 in Windows 10. I renamed my '.bashrc' -> '.bash_profile' and relaunched Git Bash. Everything's working as usual again.

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: That's almost identical to the one above, but they both work well

Comment: be careful to not override your conda .bash_profile

Comment: As at Oct 2022 once you have created ```.bashrc``` , ```.bash_profile``` is created automatically after reopening terminal

Answer (score 3):

It appears the latest version of git for Windows (2.8.3.windows.1) uses a 'profile' file now instead of the .bash_profile.  I assume this is so it isn't hidden and a valid file name.  Didn't seem to cause any issues before, but maybe it was confusing to people.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late on this answer perhaps, but you could call `bash` with the `-rcfile` argument followed by the location of your `.bashrc` file.

```
bash -rcfile C:\Users\name\.bashrc
```

I've added this to the end of my PowerShell profile (.ps1 file) so that Powershell automatically opens in `bash` and configured to my preferences.

Comment: mintty has no param -rcfile, that's why .bash_profile is needed with mintty

Comment: this worked for Terminal app that windows has: `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -rcfile 'UserPathToYourEterntity/.bashrc'`