# Git for Windows doesn't know %USERPROFILE%

Tags: windows, git, bash, windows-7

I have the same issue like [Git for Windows doesn't execute my .bashrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186840/git-for-windows-doesnt-execute-my-bashrc-file) and tried to make the same steps. But my Git Bash (2.5.0, 64bit on Windows 7, 64bit) doesn't know my `%USERPROFILE%`.

```
pitgrap@xxx MINGW64 /
$ pwd
/

pitgrap@xxx MINGW64 /
$ cd ~
bash: cd: /%USERPROFILE%: No such file or directory
```

If I run Git Bash as Administror, it works. :( 
But I don't want to run it everytime as Administrator. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new Git-for-Windows is using a `%HOME%` enviroment variable. It was set on my machine to `HOME=%USERPROFILE%`. You can't use another variable here. Remove it or change it to a real path.

See also https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/313

Comment: After did so, I still got "bash: cd: %userprofile%: No such file or directory ". I am sure I set home = %userprofile% and the keys are generated correctly under the user/user folder. Have no idea still getting this error

Comment: If you set it via the GUI, it will expand `%USERPROFILE%` to its value before saving. To get to the GUI: Start Menu -> Search for "environ" until you see "Edit the system environment variables". `HOME` *must* be set to a path and not a variable reference.

Answer (score 9):

This just has to do with how each of those different languages handle **variable expansion**.

[**cmd**](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html):  `C:\> echo %USERPROFILE%`
[**bash**](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-variables.html): `$ echo $USERPROFILE`
[**ps**](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-variables.html):     `PS> echo $env:USERPROFILE`

In windows cmd prompt, variables should be surrounded by `%` on either side
Whereas Bash and PowerShell indicate a variables by prefixing with a `$`.

Git Bash [gets all existing Windows environment variables at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38385930/1366033), while powershell tries to limit polluting the global namespace by including them under the `$env` object

[image: Shell Comparison]

If you want to confirm the shell has access to the environment variable, you can **list all variables**:

[**cmd**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5327495/1366033) *([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1))*:  `C:\> SET`
[**bash**](https://askubuntu.com/q/275965/349745) *([docs](https://ss64.com/bash/printenv.html))*: `$ printenv`
[**ps**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39800481/1366033) *([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables))*:     `PS> Get-ChildItem env:`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in terms of no prior setups needed to run

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. If you use the Git bash on Windows, you need to write `$USERPROFILE` instead of `%USERPROFILE%`.

```sh
marius@MYPC MINGW64 ~
$ echo %USERPROFILE%
%USERPROFILE%

marius@MYPC MINGW64 ~
$ echo $USERPROFILE
C:\Users\marius
```

Comment: CAPITAL LETTERS! ;)