# Set an environment variable in git bash

Tags: git, git-bash

When I punch from the windows gitbash command line:

```
set $HOME = c
```

and do :

```
echo $HOME
```

It does not set it to `c`? How can I change/set the value of an environment variable?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

A normal variable is set by simply assigning it a value; note that no whitespace is allowed around the `=`:

```
HOME=c
```

An environment variable is a regular variable that has been marked for export to the environment.

```
export HOME
HOME=c
```

You can combine the assignment with the `export` statement.

```
export HOME=c
```

Comment: So what does OP's `set` do?

Comment: Assuming a "normal" value of `$HOME` (such that the unquoted expansion results in a single word), it sets the first three positional parameters to the values of of `$HOME`, `=`, and `c`, respectively. For example, `set a b c; echo "$2"` would output `b`.

Comment: Also true for bash in general.

Comment: Worth to note that this variable will NOT be Windows Environment Variables.  
I mean, opening Windows Settings -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables you cannot find them nor for User neither for System.  
To achieve this goal use ``  setx My_VARIABLE "my value"  ``

Answer (score 63):

If you want to set environment variables permanently in Git-Bash, you have two options:

1. Set a regular Windows environment variable. Git-bash gets all existing Windows environment variables at startup.
2. Set up environment variables in `.bash_profile` file.

`.bash_profile` is by default located in a user home folder, like `C:\users\userName\git-home\.bash_profile`. You can change the path to the bash home folder by setting `HOME` Windows environment variable.

`.bash_profile` file uses the regular Bash syntax and commands

```
# Export a variable in .bash_profile
export DIR=c:\dir
# Nix path style works too
export DIR=/c/dir

# And don't forget to add quotes if a variable contains whitespaces
export ANOTHER_DIR="c:\some dir"
```

Read more information about [Bash configurations files](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-bashrc.html).

Comment: You may not have answered the OP question but you have certainly helped me out with my question. I was trying to override the PERL5LIB environment variable for Git Bash on Windows and this allowed me to do it easily.

Comment: You might want to edit #1 to mention it's the same command as in a Windows shell except with different syntax (`setx foo bar` versus `setx foo=bar`).  I misread what you were saying with that answer since you didn't mention setx.

Comment: For some reason, Git Bash is ignoring my Windows' HOME environment variable. Meaning, it's not using my gitconfig but using its own inside Git/etc.

Comment: but you couldn't set HOME or HOMEDRIVE via this method, correct? since you already known .bash_profile is under HOME.

Answer (score 8):

Creating a .bashrc file in your home directory also works.  That way you don't have to copy your .bash_profile every time you install a new version of git bash.

Answer (score 1):

1. Temporarily change the environment variable

> export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11"

Verify it's been changed

> mvn -version

NOTE: Don't verify this via

> java -version

2. Permenantly change the environment variable

> setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17"

NOTE: necessary to restart Git Bash first