# How to set environment variables in git bash?

Tags: windows, bash, environment-variables

I use windows and I'm trying to run flask through Git Bash and ConEmu. I entered the following commands:

```
set FLASK_APP=application.py
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
set DATABASE_URL=postgres://someurl
flask run
```

and this was the result:

```
* Environment: production
WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
```

Do I need to write the commands directly into the bash file?

EDIT: I tried setting the variables in bash_profile, but that did not change the results I got. (I did remember to restart my terminal.)

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169721/set-an-environment-variable-in-git-bash)

Comment: Basically, git bash is bash, which is a Unix shell, not an incarnation of CMD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set it locally for the command:

```
FLASK_APP=application.py FLASK_DEBUG=1 DATABASE_URL=postgres://someurl flask run
```

Or you can set it permanently for the session:

```
export FLASK_APP=application.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1 
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://someurl 
flask run
```

The point is: there is no `set var=value` in git bash as you would use in a CMD.
`set`, in bash, [has another meaning](https://ss64.com/bash/set.html).

> Change the value of a shell option and set the positional parameters