# Windows environmental variable keeps loading despite removing

Tags: windows, powershell, git-bash

I don't remember how exactly, but I had set up an environmental variable on Windows. This is not inside the Windows advanced settings -> *Environmental Variables*.

I have tried to unset it in many ways including, from `git-bash`:

```
$ unset DUMMY
$ env | grep DUMMY
```

This works only for the current session. When I restart or open a new terminal I can still see the variable set. I also tried to unset it from PowerShell as follows:

```
$ Remove-Item Env:\DUMMY
```

But like the previous technique, this is only for the current session. How can I find where this environmental variable is being loaded?

PS: To clarify, this is an environment variable that I created myself some weeks ago, but I forgot where/how I had set it to stay persistent.

Comment: Possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222724/command-line-to-remove-an-environment-variable-from-the-os-level-configuration

Comment: If the variable is not among the system or user environment variables you probably added the variable definition to a [PowerShell profile](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx). Another possible location might be a [`.bash_profile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38385930/1630171) in your Git home, but then the variable shouldn't be showing up in a PowerShell console.

Comment: @timl you are right... I had set it using the `setx` command and therefore the solution in the link you provided, has worked perfectly. Thanks