# Display all environment variables from a running PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I need to display all configured environment variables in a PowerShell script at runtime. Normally when displaying environment variables I can just use one of the following at the shell (among other techniques, but these are simple):

```
gci env:*
ls Env:
```

However, I have a script being called from another program, and when I use one of the above calls in the script, instead of being presented with environment variables and their values, I instead get a list of `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` types instead of the variables and their values. Inside of a PowerShell script, how can I display all environment variables?

Comment: FYI for most of the answers in this thread: `gci` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Shorter version:

```
gci env:* | sort-object name
```

This will display both the name and value.

Comment: Could you explain why it behaves like that and how your command fixes it, please?

Comment: That's the sign of progress because `env` was too easy. Damn you M$ people.

Comment: I want to add that this behavior was something I encountered in PowerShell 4, but as of 5.1+ I can use the variants shown in the question within a script and expect it to display the variable name and value. Note that `gci env:` will now sort the variables by `Name`. though `gci env:*` does *not*.

Comment: I'm assuming that by _shorter_ you mean relative to  the [OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39800606/45375). However, the omission of `Out-String` is crucial with respect to the question as asked. If you simply want to list all environment variables including their values in PowerShell with nice formatting, `gci env:` will do (no need for `*`, no need for `Sort-Object`, as without the `*` the output is automatically sorted by name).

Comment: What's wrong with `gci env:|ft`? Suffering from something like getting ellipsis for too long values?

Answer (score 92):

Shortest version (with variables sorted by name):

```
gci env:
```

Answer (score 20):

I finally fumbled my way into a solution by iterating over each entry in the dictionary:

```
(gci env:*).GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name | Out-String
```

Comment: doesn't run on Linux for me.  Are you missing `gci` to get the child items?

Comment: I haven't tried this on powershell core, but gci is in my answer. Note that this question is for [powershell] and not [powershell-core], so solutions may not work for the latter.

Comment: You can simplify to `gci env: | Out-String` (in _both_ PowerShell editions). Please reconsider which answer you've accepted, given that you clearly needed an _explicit stringification_ of the `[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]` instances (though it is unclear why), which the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45570821/45375) lacks. As it stands, the currently accepted answer doesn't addresses your problem, and is also a  poor answer to the _general_ question of how to list environment variables in PowerShell, given that `gci env:` is enough.

Answer (score 16):

> Short version with a wild card **filter**:

```
gci env: | where name -like 'Pro*'
```

Comment: You can also skip the pipeline and simply use a wildcard filter with `Get-ChildItem`. For example: `gci env:Pro*`

Answer (score 15):

I don't think any of the answers provided are related to the question.
The OP is getting the list of Object Types (which are the same for each member) and not the actual variable names and values.
This is what you are after:

```
gci env:* | select Name,Value
```

Short for:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:* | Select-Object -Property Name,Value
```

Comment: Is the `*` actually needed? I think it's not.

Comment: It's not needed. People seem to use it out of habit. When using Get-ChildItem Env: without the asterisk, it's automatically sorted by name. It is not sorted when using the wildcard.

Answer (score 12):

This command works also:

```
dir env:
```

Comment: `dir` and `gci` are both aliases for `Get-ChildItem`

Answer (score 7):

Long environment variable values get truncated by default.

This is one quick way to get a sorted list of environment variables, with full values:

```
Get-ChildItem env:* | Sort-Object Name | Format-List
```

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr**

Since you were looking for a *friendly string representation* of the environment-variable name-value pairs:

```bash
gci env: | oss
```

`oss` is a built-in wrapper function for `Out-String -Stream`, and therefore returns each name-value pair as its own string; pipe to `Out-String` (without `-Stream`) to get a *single, multi-line* string (albeit one that invariably and unexpectedly has a *trailing newline* - see [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444)).

---

To **list the *names and values* of all environment variables** in PowerShell, **sorted by name**,<sup>[1]</sup> list the content (child items) of the `env:` [PowerShell drive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) using the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet (a built-in alias of which is `gci`):

```bash
# 'gci' is a built-in alias of the 'Get-ChildItem' cmdlet.
# Avoid alias 'ls', because on Unix-like platforms 
# it isn't defined and instead refers to the standard utility of that name.
# The output is implicitly *sorted by variable name*.
gci env:

# Use *wildcards* to list variables by *name pattern*; e.g, all whose
# name starts with "home"
gci env:home*
```

**The above outputs *objects***, namely instances of [`[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.DictionaryEntry) **describing each variable as a *name-value pair***, with `.Key` (`.Name`) and `.Value` properties. PowerShell's [for-display formatting system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805771/45375) automatically renders these in a friendly two-column format.

- To **list environment-variable *names* only:**

  ```bash
  gci env: -Name

  # Alternative, using property access:
  (gci env:).Name
  ```
- To **get a specific environment variable's *value***, e.g. the value of `USERNAME`, it's easiest to use [namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375):

  ```bash
  # Output the value of environment variable "USERNAME"
  $env:USERNAME

  # Alternative, using gc (alias of Get-Content)
  # Needed if the name is stored in a variable.
  gc env:USERNAME
  ```

**If you *stringify* these objects with (potentially implied) `.ToString()`**:

- In *Windows PowerShell*, they uselessly stringify as their *type name*, i.e. as verbatim `'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry'`
- In *PowerShell (Core) 7*, they now more meaningfully stringify as `'[<name>, <value>]'`
- Try with (`%` is a built-in alias of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet):

  ```bash
  gci env: | % tostring

  # Ditto with Write-Host, which also uses .ToString() stringification
  gci env: | Write-Host
  ```

**If you want to stringify them *as they would print to the display*, using the friendly two-column format**, use the [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) cmdlet:

```bash
# Outputs *friendly* string representations
gci env: | oss # 'oss' is a built-in wrapper function for 'Out-String -Stream'
```

Note: If you use `Out-String` without `-Stream`, you get a *single, multi-line* string as the output, though note that it will have a *trailing newline*.<sup>[2]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Note that using `Get-ChildItem` / `gci` with `env:*`, i.e. wildcard character `*` following the drive specification `env:` - is not only unnecessary for getting *all* variables, it actually results in *unsorted* output.</sup>

<sup>[2] That a trailing newline is invariably appended is problematic, as discussed in [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to get all environment variables in Powershell

```
 [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables()
 or
 dir env:
```

To get environment variable by name

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME")
 $env:USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PowerShell Core(6 or above) (pwsh: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), you can also use `ls env:`

Comment: What is `list`?  I see no such command in PowerShell (Core) v7.2.4.  Did you mean `ls`?  If so, that's [yet another alias for `Get-ChildItem`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800481/display-all-environment-variables-from-a-running-powershell-script#comment122736361_69407908) and also already stated in the question.

Comment: Yeah, it should be `ls`, sorry for the miss-leading, thanks for your correction @LanceU.Matthews