# How to print environment variables to the console in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm starting to use PowerShell and am trying to figure out how to `echo` a system environment variable to the console to read it.

Neither of the below are working. The first just prints `%PATH%`, and the second prints nothing.

```
echo %PATH%
echo $PATH
```

Comment: `echo $env:Path`

Comment: **See Also**: [Display all environment variables from a running PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39800481/1366033)

Answer (score 595, accepted):

Prefix the variable name with `env`:

```
$env:path
```

For example, if you want to print the value of environment value `MINISHIFT_USERNAME`, then command will be:

```
$env:MINISHIFT_USERNAME
```

You can also enumerate all variables via the `env` drive:

```
Get-ChildItem env:
```

Comment: I like `$Env:Path.Split(';')` myself (output one directory per line).

Comment: For sure, or `$env:Path -split ';'`

Comment: @AmirKatz The output is the same, because the two operations do the exact same thing :) `-split` is a regex operator, `String.Split()` is not

Comment: for short use `gci env:`

Comment: @navigaid `get-alias` lists more, including `gal` (which can be found with `get-alias | where {$_.Name -like '*al*'}`, furthermore `gal | gm` shows all property names  `where` can filter on. `get-command` (`gcm`), `get-help` (`help`), `help gcm`, and `help help`, may also be helpful.

Comment: I Mac I had to use `$env:PATH`, with uppercase PATH.

Comment: Is "MINISHIFT_USERNAME" something particular to this issue or it is just a variable name? I googled it and it seems related to "red hat"

Comment: @Santropedro I'm afraid I do not recall why I used that particular example 6 years ago :)

Answer (score 16):

The following works best, in my opinion:

```
Get-Item Env:PATH
```

1. It's shorter and, therefore, a little easier to remember than `Get-ChildItem` (There's no hierarchy with environment variables).
2. The command is symmetrical to one of the ways being used for [setting environment variables with Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-item?view=powershell-7). (EX: `Set-Item -Path env:SomeVariable -Value "Some Value"`)
3. If you get in the habit of doing it this way, you'll remember how to list all Environment variables: simply omit the entry portion. (EX: `Get-Item Env:`)

I found the syntax odd at first, but things started making more sense after I understood the notion of [Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-6#viewing-provider-data). Essentially PowerShell lets you navigate disparate components of the system in a way that's analogous to a file system.

What's the point of the trailing colon in `Env:` ? Try listing all of the "drives" available through Providers like this:

```
PS> Get-PSDrive
```

I only see a few results (*Alias, C, Cert, D, Env, Function, HKCU, HKLM, Variable, WSMan*). It becomes obvious that `Env` is simply a specific "drive", and the colon is the familiar syntax to anyone who's worked with Windows.

You can traverse through the drives like this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows
Get-Item C:
Get-Item Env:
Get-Item HKLM:
Get-ChildItem HKLM:SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 15):

In addition to Mathias answer.

Although not mentioned in OP, if you also need to see the *Powershell* specific/related internal variables, you need to use `Get-Variable`:

```bsh
$ Get-Variable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
$                              name
?                              True
^                              gci
args                           {}
ChocolateyTabSettings          @{AllCommands=False}
ConfirmPreference              High
DebugPreference                SilentlyContinue
EnabledExperimentalFeatures    {}
Error                          {System.Management.Automation.ParseException: At line:1 char:1...
ErrorActionPreference          Continue
ErrorView                      NormalView
ExecutionContext               System.Management.Automation.EngineIntrinsics
false                          False
FormatEnumerationLimit         4
...
```

These also include stuff you may have set in your profile startup script.

Answer (score 9):

As a complementary to other answers,

In the case of listing all Environment Variables, to concise the commands, you can use `dir`, `ls`, and `gci` (an acronym for Get-ChildItem) as they are three aliases of `Get-ChildItem`.

So, all of the following commands are equal and can be used in this context:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

or

```
dir Env:
```

or

```
ls Env:
```

or

```
gci Env:
```

More information in [shellgeek](https://shellgeek.com/powershell-print-environment-variables/).

---

Also, as a practical use case, you can get an alphabetically sorted list of Environment Variables based on `Name` or `Value` like this:

```
Get-ChildItem Env: | Sort Name
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem Env: | Sort Value
```

**FYI**: You cannot replace `Get-ChildItem Env:` with `Get-Item Env:` in the above commands (The list won't be sorted and remains unchanged). So, in such cases, the `Get-ChildItem` might be preferred to the `Get-Item` mentioned in [this answer by BitBite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64546971/9539287).

Finally, you can sort the value of a specific record of Environment Variables like this:

```
(Get-ChildItem Env:PATH).Value.Split(';') | Sort
```

Comment: This might not be top but is far and away the most concise and useful answer.

Answer (score 7):

I ran across this myself. I wanted to look at the paths but have each on a separate line. This prints out the path, and splits it by the semicolon.

`$env:path.Split(";")`