# How to use an environment variable in PowerShell console?

Tags: powershell, command-line

I have an environment variable named `GOPATH`. In old style command shell I could run the command `%GOPATH%\bin\hello` like this:

[image]

Is there an equivalently simple command in Windows PowerShell?

---

### EDIT

I am not trying to print the environment variable. I am trying to USE it.

The variable is set correctly:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> echo $env:gopath
C:\per\go
```

Now I want to actually use this in a command line call, and it fails:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> $env:gopath\bin\hello
At line:1 char:12
+ $env:gopath\bin\hello
+            ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\bin\hello' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [],        ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: Use `$Env:GOPATH`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print environment variables to console in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861082/how-to-print-environment-variables-to-console-in-powershell)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I am not trying to PRINT. I am trying to USE.

Comment: And when printing you don't **use** the var?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `$env:[Variablename]`

For example:

```
$env:Appdata
```

or

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME
```

using your example:

```
$env:GOPATH
```

To use this to execute a script use

```
& "$env:GOPATH\bin\hello"
```

Answer (score 7):

Using an environment variable in a path to invoke a command would require either [dot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) [notation](https://ss64.com/ps/source.html) or the [call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-) [operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html). The quotation marks expand the variable and the call operator invokes the path.

#### Dot Notation

`. "$env:M2_Home\bin\mvn.cmd"`

#### Call Operator

`& "$env:M2_Home\bin\mvn.cmd"`

Comment: The call operator had already been suggested. Using the dot-sourcing operator would work too, but that is only incidental. The operator is for running (PowerShell) scripts in the current context as opposed to running them in a child context via the call operator, but external commands are running in a separate process anyway, so there's no advantage in using `.` over `&`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use start-process -NoNewWindow to run it.

```
C:\windows\system32> start-process -nonewwindow $env:gopath\bin\hello.exe
C:\windows\system32Hello, Go examples!
>
```

This is much more verbose obviously and puts the command prompt at an odd looking prompt: `>`. But it does work.