# Setting environment variables in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, environment-variables

In `cmd`, you could access `cmd` environment variables outside of `cmd`, but is there a way to accomplish that is powershell?

---

**BACKGROUND:**
In command-prompt (`cmd.exe`), there are environment variables like `%COMSPEC%` and `%PROGRAMFILES%` that you could use outside of `cmd` an din file explorer and other places (i. e. shortcuts) just by typing in `%VariableName%` somewhere (this is how I see a lot of people accessing their `appdata` folders) but I have yet to find a way to do it in powershell. In `cmd`, you could even define a variable with `setx` nd be able to use it outside of cmd. Ex:

```
setx testbat "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\Programs\test.bat"
```

Then you could use it like this in shortcuts:

```
%testbat%
```

<sub>[Shortcut Wizard with cmd variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swUAs.png)</sub>

However, I have not been able to replicate this with Powershell variables.

---

**What I've tried:**

1. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861082/how-to-print-environment-variables-to-the-console-in-powershell/50861113#50861113) and wondered if making an environment variable in powershell with this in mind could be possible:

```
$env:test = "C:\Users\Neko"
```

Then I restarted and tried using this both in `cmd` and in the search prompt ([search prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyLds.png))

```
C:\Users\Neko>cd %test%
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\Users\Neko>echo %test%
%test%
```

Sure enough, it didn't even show up in powershell when I did `gci env:` after the restart
Since this didn't work I deleted the variable and had an idea:

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> gci env:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData
APPDATA                        C:\Users\Neko\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles             C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)        C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432             C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME                   XXXXXXXXX
ComSpec                        C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData                     C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
HOMEDRIVE                      C:
HOMEPATH                       \Users\Neko
LOCALAPPDATA                   C:\Users\Neko\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER                    \\XXXXXXXXX
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS           8
OneDrive                       C:\Users\Neko\OneDrive
OneDriveConsumer               C:\Users\Neko\OneDrive
OS                             Windows_NT
POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHA... MSI:Windows 10 Pro Education
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE         AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER           Intel64 Family 6 Model 126 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL                6
PROCESSOR_REVISION             7e05
ProgramData                    C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles                   C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)              C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432                   C:\Program Files
PSModulePath                   C:\Users\Neko\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\M...
PUBLIC                         C:\Users\Public
SystemDrive                    C:
SystemRoot                     C:\Windows
TEMP                           C:\Users\Neko\AppData\Local\Temp
test                           C:\Users\Neko
TMP                            C:\Users\Neko\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN                     XXXXXXXXX
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE      XXXXXXXXX
USERNAME                       Neko
USERPROFILE                    C:\Users\Neko
windir                         C:\Windows
WSLENV                         WT_SESSION::WT_PROFILE_ID
WT_PROFILE_ID                  XXXXXXXXX
WT_SESSION                     XXXXXXXXX


PS C:\Users\Neko> del "env:test"
PS C:\Users\Neko> gci env:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData
APPDATA                        C:\Users\Neko\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles             C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)        C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432             C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME                   XXXXXXXXX
ComSpec                        C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData                     C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
HOMEDRIVE                      C:
HOMEPATH                       \Users\Neko
LOCALAPPDATA                   C:\Users\Neko\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER                    \\XXXXXXXXX
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS           8
OneDrive                       C:\Users\Neko\OneDrive
OneDriveConsumer               C:\Users\Neko\OneDrive
OS                             Windows_NT
Path                           C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPo...
PATHEXT                        .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHA... MSI:Windows 10 Pro Education
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE         AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER           Intel64 Family 6 Model 126 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL                6
PROCESSOR_REVISION             7e05
ProgramData                    C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles                   C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)              C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432                   C:\Program Files
PSModulePath                   C:\Users\Neko\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\M...
PUBLIC                         C:\Users\Public
SystemDrive                    C:
SystemRoot                     C:\Windows
TEMP                           C:\Users\Neko\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP                            C:\Users\Neko\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN                     XXXXXXXXX
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE      XXXXXXXXX
USERNAME                       Neko
USERPROFILE                    C:\Users\Neko
windir                         C:\Windows
WSLENV                         WT_SESSION::WT_PROFILE_ID
WT_PROFILE_ID                  XXXXXXXXX
WT_SESSION                     XXXXXXXXX
```

2. I then checked to see if the `cmd` `set` command beared the same results as `gci env:` and it did, so I then tried to use `setx` to see if it appeared in powershell as well:

```
setx test "Test"
```

And after a restart, it did

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> $env:test
Test
```

I realized that the variables all were stored in the registry and that I could edit the registry of course with:

```
Set-Itemproperty -path 'HKCU:\Environment' -Name 'Test' -value 'Test'
```

But it doesn't feel the same as something like `setx`

---

**CONCLUSION**: 
I want to learn if there is a *true-powershell*-esque command that can define environemnt variables that I can use outside of powershell like `setx` can in cmd. **I am not looking for full scripts** just commands or something like `$env:variable = "value"`.

---

**UPDATE**: 
Yes, you can create a function to do this as well, technically a one-liner possibly, not what I'm looking for. I want to be able to create environment variables in powershell with *built in cmdlets*. Something "true-powershell"

Comment: take a look at the `[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable()` static method. it accepts machine/user/process for the exact environment, and the variable name. the matching `Set` does the same and accepts a value.

Comment: Add `/m` to your setx command: 

`setx testbat "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\Programs\test.bat" /m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell itself provides these methods to interact with environment variables:

- The Environment provider drive
- The Item cmdlets
- The .NET System.Environment class
- On Windows, the System Control Panel

So, to set a persistent environment variable (PSModulePath) to a value `$newpath` at machine level you might use

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", $newpath, 'Machine')
```

To get an environment variable you might use

```
$path = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PSModulePath', 'Machine')
```

or the variable syntax

```
$Env:PSModulePath
```

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7) the documentation.

Comment: When I do this, 1. It doesn't show up when I do the "variable syntax" `$env:name` and 2 does not allow me to use it if non ps context. Doesn't affect the registry either so I think this is only powershell variable. Also does not show up in `gci env:`

Comment: Environment variables are read at startup... so you have to restart powershell and then the $env:name will show up... There's also another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381650/how-to-update-windows-powershell-session-environment-variables-from-registry) about this....

Comment: thank you, I restarted and now it works. Can you explain how this works because as far as I can see it doesn't change anything in the registry or in other places?

Comment: It's saved to the registry on windows. It depends on the OS your are running and which location you have chosen (Machine, User, Process). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netcore-3.1). At least for machine level entries the registry location is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment

Comment: I see... Is there a specific reason for the first argument to be double-quoted and the last to be single-quoted in your answer?

Comment: No.. both quote methods are valid. The only difference is, that within single quotes no variables are expanded...