# I can't run any flutter command in vs code terminal

Tags: flutter, powershell, windows-terminal

When i try to run any flutter command on powershell into vs code, it load infinitelly and doesn't finish. However, when I run the same command on my powershell out of vs code, it works. Please someone help me.

[vs code terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Eu06.png)
[the same command running in the external powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wANrC.jpg)

I verified my environment variables, and it's ok;
I tried to reinstall both vs code and flutter, including switching the flutter directory, but the problem exits yet.

Comment: In PowerShell check if PATH contains you flutter `bin` directory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861082/how-to-print-environment-variables-to-the-console-in-powershell

Comment: after entering command just then again hit enter button or ctr+c it work. its weird behaviour i am also faced in my windows system.

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh when i press enter, nothing happens, and whe i press ctrl c , i get an alert message ask if I want to cancel the proccess

Comment: @eeqk yes, the PATH has my flutter bin directory, and dart bin directory also.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was that I was running the terminal as admin, and vs code not. Now the problem is how to run any flutter command without admin permission and without errors, and this is another topic. Thanks for the help