# How to returne multiline with foreach $element in $var

Tags: powershell

My question is little be stupid but i'm a beginner and i didn't found on the web and forum what i want to do.

```
$Servers = $(Window.FindName("Server_list").SelectedItems
```

When i return this var, i have all my servers i had selected but on  line like this

```
server1 server2 server3 server4 ...
```

For me i need to do a Foreach like this

```
Foreach ($element in $Servers)
{
*element of my var* {"`r"}
}
```

The result i should have is

```
server1
server2
server3
etc
```

I think i'm not to far of the answer but my brain start to burn with my beginner level.

Thank you for your idea and answer.

Comment: Sounds like you want `$servers -join [Environment]::NewLine`

Answer (score 1):

From `$Window.FindName("Server_list").SelectedItems` (note that I've removed what I presume to be an extraneous `(`) I infer that you're getting a WPF list view's `.SelectedItems` property value.

This value is a *collection* (strictly speaking: an object that implements the `IList` interface)<sup>[1]</sup>, which has two implications in PowerShell:

- You can *enumerate* the collection (iterate over its elements) in a `foreach` loop or, implicitly, in the *pipeline* (see bottom section for a `ForEach-Object` example). Additionally, many PowerShell *operators* either operate exclusively on or *can also* operate on collections (typically, on the LHS), in which case the collection is also implicitly enumerated and the operation performed on each element, such as shown with the `-join` operator below.
- When you print the collection to the console (host), PowerShell's default output formatting system prints each element on its own line *by default* (see bottom section).

It sounds like you truly need to **build a *multi-line string* programmatically**:

To create a **plain-text** multi-line string, [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)'s solution based on the [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) operator is the right one:

```sh
# Note: Since -join is a *string* operator, any LHS elements
#       that aren't already strings are automatically stringified with .ToString()
$Servers -join "`n"
```

Note that I'm using `` "`n" ``, a Unix-format LF newline, which is usually sufficient. If you want to use Windows-format CRLF newlines, use `` "`r`n" ``. For the *platform-native* newline sequence, use `[Environment]::NewLine`.

However, if the text is to be rendered as **HTML**, actual *newlines aren't sufficient*: they get converted to *spaces*. Instead, you must join the server names with `<br>` elements:

```sh
# Create a multi-line *HTML* string
$Servers -join '<br>'
```

##### Console-output considerations:

The following array-based example demonstrates the default to-display behavior with string collections (arrays):

```sh
PS> $Servers = 'server1', 'server2', 'server3'; $Servers # output
server1
server2
server3
```

Note that `$Servers` by itself is essentially the same as `Write-Output $Servers`, thanks to PowerShell's [*implicit* output behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792182/45375).

If the elements of collection `$Servers` aren't actually *strings*, you'll get different, richer output: depending on the number of properties of the objects, you'll get *table*-formatted (<= 4 properties) or *list*-formatted (5 or more properties, each property on its own line) output by default.

If you just want the *string representations* of these elements, as reported by their `.ToString()` method, use the following:

```sh
$Servers | ForEach-Object ToString
```

By contrast, using [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) - which is meant for to-display output, not for *data* output - stringifies collections differently (and often unhelpfully); it outputs a *single* line, with the (stringified) collection elements joined *with spaces*, and uses simple `.ToString()` stringification, not PowerShell's rich [output-formatting system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805771/45375).

```sh
PS> Write-Host $Servers
server1 server2 server3
```

However, you can instruct `Write-Host` to use newlines (line breaks) instead:

```sh
PS> Write-Host -Separator "`n" $Servers
server1
server2
server3
```

However, remember that this generates *for-display* output, not *data* (see below).

---

<sup>[1] For a summary of which types PowerShell enumerates by default, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530467/45375).</sup>

Comment: What does this question have to do with WPF?

Comment: @Joe, WPF is ultimately _incidental_ to this answer, but `$Windows.FindName(...)` suggests the use of the [`FrameworkElement.FindName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname#system-windows-frameworkelement-findname(system-string)) method, which the derived [`System.Windows.Windows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window) WPF class inherits. What matters is that `$Servers` contains, loosely speaking, a _collection_ of items.

Comment: @Joe, and I only just now saw there's an explicit `wpf` _tag_ on the question... The only aspect that matters somewhat is what type of objects the collection returned by `.SelectedItems` contains - given the abstract, non-generic `IList` interface, I couldn't tell. Knowing WPF only superficially: can the type vary?

Comment: No worries.  I just missed the reference.

Comment: Sorry for the comprehension of WPF in this code.
My script as 340line and with my job i can't upload the whole code.
However i had try 
`
$Servers -join "`n"
`
On console pane i have multiline but on my wpf i have one line.

I try to do :
`
$Test = $($Server) -join "`n"
`
And call $Test but same result, only one line. 

I had try to do this one too:
`
Foreach ($element in $Servers)
{
$element -join "`n"
}
`
However same result.
I probably miss understanding something :/

Comment: @YannM, it sounds like the multi-line string is rendered _as HTML_, in which case regular newlines aren't enough - please see my update (I've moved the console considerations to a separate section at the bottom).