# PowerShell 5.1 I am not getting the expected output in this simple example

Tags: powershell

```
$res = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select * from customer" -ServerInstance "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -Database "Database1" -OutputAs DataTables

$res | Where-Object FirstName -eq "John"
$res.Where({$_.FirstName -eq "John"})
```

This is the output:

```
Id FirstName City   
-- --------- ----   
 1 John      Augusta
 1 John      Augusta
```

I was expecting this:

```
Id FirstName City   
-- --------- ----   
 1 John      Augusta

Id FirstName City   
-- --------- ----   
 1 John      Augusta
```

Comment: Pipe to `Format-Table` to force separate tables: `$res | Where-Object FirstName -eq "John" | Format-Table` and `$res.Where({$_.FirstName -eq "John"}) | Format-Table`

Comment: PowerShell optimizes the output for you and concatenates similar objects with the same properties into one table ... neat huh?

Comment: @Olaf is that sarcasm, lol

Comment: Actually not ... for me that is a convenience function. If you don't want it you can use the tip zett42 gave in his comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on the helpful comments:

The **behavior is by design**:

- Objects output by a given script or a single interactively submitted command line are all sent to the success output stream of a *single* pipeline.
- When output from a pipeline is neither captured nor redirected, **PowerShell applies [for-display output formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805771/45375) to *all* output objects in the success output stream of a given pipeline**, and if the *first* output object implicitly selects *tabular* formatting, all subsequent objects *of the same type* are formatted as part of the *same table* that is printed to the host (display, terminal).

  - Things get tricky if subsequent objects are of a *different* type as well as if they're also `[pscustomobject]` instances, but with different property sets - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55504393/45375) for more information.

---

**If you want to format a given command's output *individually***, you have three basic options, all of which are *suboptimal* in case you also want to option to later *programmatically process* the output, not just format it *for display*:

- Send the output directly to the *host*, using [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host):

  ```bash
  $res | Where-Object FirstName -eq "John" | Out-Host
  ```

  - This *bypasses* the success output stream, meaning that this output *cannot be captured or redirected*.
- Use a `Format-*` cmdlet such as [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) *explicitly*:

  ```bash
  $res | Where-Object FirstName -eq "John" | Format-Table
  ```

  - This sends objects representing *formatting instructions* rather than the original objects to the success output stream, which the *host* (as the default output target) renders correctly, but these objects are meaningless for further *programmatic* processing.
- Use [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) (possibly preceded by a call to a `Format-*` cmdlet to select the kind of formatting and/or control the specifics of the formatting):

  ```bash
  $res | Where-Object FirstName -eq "John" | Out-String
  ```

  - This sends a single, multi-line *string* to the success output stream that contains the same representation you would see in the host with `Out-Host`<sup>[1]</sup> and since *strings* always render as-is, you'll see the same host output; in *programmatic* processing, these strings are relatively more meaningful than the formatting-instruction objects output by `Format-*` cmdlets, but still amount to a loss of information compared to the original output objects.

---

<sup>[1] Unfortunately, `Out-String` always appends a *trailing newline* to this representation; this problematic behavior is the subject of [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444). As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, using `Out-String -Stream` avoids this problem, albeit at the expense of sending the lines of the multi-line string representation *individually* to the output stream; To avoid that, you can use `` (... | Out-String -Stream) -join "`n" ``</sup>

Comment: Thanks, @zett42; I've updated the footnote based on your feedback. As for a future fix: A switch would be an improvement, but, honestly, I wish they'd just fix the default behavior: there was never a good reason for it to begin with.