# PowerShell - Adjust output header groups

Tags: powershell

So, I have a simple script that's running test-netconnection against a number of different servers and ports, to verify that the SCCM client will have the necessary connectivity. I'm collecting a couple of variables at the start, and I'm static setting a few others because they're not site specific and will be used for all tests.

But the issue is that I want to have a descriptor print out on the screen before each section, followed by the output table, just to make the output easier to read at a glance. But it's not doing that at all, and I have no idea how to get it to do that. So basically I want something like this:

```
Testing connectivity to the local distribution point
ComputerName    RemoteAddress   RemotePort        TCPTestSucceeded
--------------  -----------     ----------------  ---------------- 
DPserver        192.168.1.1     80                True
DPserver        192.168.1.1     443               True

Testing Connectivity to the Management Points
ComputerName    RemoteAddress   RemotePort        TCPTestSucceeded
--------------  -----------     ----------------  ---------------- 
MPserver        192.168.1.1     80                True
MPserver        192.168.1.1     443               True
```

But instead, I'm getting this (edited to reflect the actual current results, following the change recommended by novice):

```
Testing connectivity to the local distribution point

Testing connectivity to the management points
ComputerName                 RemoteAddress RemotePort TcpTestSucceeded
------------                 ------------- ---------- ----------------
server1                      10.90.82.131          80             True
server1                      10.90.82.131         443             True
server1                      10.90.82.131        8005             True
server2                      10.88.166.167      10123             True
server2                      10.88.166.167         80             True
server2                      10.88.166.167        443             True
server3                      10.88.166.207      10123             True
server3                      10.88.166.207         80             True
server3                      10.88.166.207        443             True
server4                      10.88.167.78       10123             True
server4                      10.88.167.78          80             True
server4                      10.88.167.78         443             True
Testing connectivity to the software update points
server5                      10.88.167.80          80             True
server5                      10.88.167.80        8530             True
server5                      10.88.167.80         443            False
server5                      10.88.167.80        8531             True
server6                      10.88.167.81          80             True
server6                      10.88.167.81        8530             True
server6                      10.88.167.81         443            False
server6                      10.88.167.81        8531             True
```

Part of the issue is that the error is appearing, even though I have -ErrorAction set to SilentlyContinue, and then part of the issue is that the header is only appearing once. I'm guessing I would have to group up the results in some manner to get the header to appear for each group, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Can anyone assist? This is the full script I have right now (with the static server names changed for posting):

```
$DP = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the FQDN for the local DP'
$MP1 = 'MP1'
$MP2 = 'MP2'
$MP3 = 'MP3'
$SUP1 = 'SUP1'
$SUP2 = 'SUP2'
$Client = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the workstation to test from'

Enter-PSSession $Client

Write-Host 'Testing connectivity to the local distribution point'
Test-NetConnection -Port 80 $DP -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 443 $DP -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 8005 $DP -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded

Write-Host 'Testing connectivity to the management points'
Test-NetConnection -Port 10123 $MP1 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 80 $MP1 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 443 $MP1 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 10123 $MP2 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 80 $MP2 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 443 $MP2 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 10123 $MP3 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 80 $MP3 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 443 $MP3 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -

Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Write-Host 'Testing connectivity to the software update points'
Test-NetConnection -Port 80 $SUP1 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 8530 $SUP1 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 443 $SUP1 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 8531 $SUP1 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 80 $SUP2 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 8530 $SUP2 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 443 $SUP2 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded
Test-NetConnection -Port 8531 $SUP2 -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property ComputerName,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,TCPTestSucceeded

Exit-PSSession
```

Also, I know I can do for-each loops for some of the sections, but I want to get this working as-is first, and then figure out the for-each loops. (I'm VERY much a novice scripter.)

Comment: If I understand your questions correct. Your main question is answered here: [PowerShell 5.1 I am not getting the expected output in this simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72586544/1701026), but in your case it might simply be enough to remove the `Write-Host` in front of the messages with will put the messages on the [success stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams) and therefore restart the table outputs.

Answer (score 0):

There are no errors but warnings and might you want to silent them as well.

Use below in top of your code.

`$WarningPreference='SilentlyContinue'`

Comment: Yep, that got rid of the warnings, so that helps. The section comments and grouping are still an issue though.