# Adding Header to the Variable

Tags: powershell

This is probably a dumb question but I cant seem to figure it out. How do I add a header to already existing variable? I have a variable with bunch of strings in it and I am trying to make it so it has a header which will simplify the script later on. Just as an example

```
$test = 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Which comes out to be:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $test
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Where as what I want it to do is:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $test
Numbers
--------
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Additionally when implementing for each loop is it possible to add a blank header like to existing variable (from which foreach loop is running) and fill it automatically? for example going from original variable:

```
Letters   Value 
-------   -----  
a         10
b         15
c         23
d         25
```

To after for each loop:

```
Letters   Value   Numbers
-------   -----   ------
a         10        1
b         15        2
c         23        3
d         25        4
```

This is a super generic example but basically i have one object with headers and when using a function someone made I am trying to populate the table with output of that function, the issue is that its returning stuff with no header and just returns the output only so I cant even make a hash table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, your variable is a list of integers.

That's why there's no header.

If your variable were something else, like, a custom object, it would be displayed with headers.

To make your example a list of custom objects:

```
$test = 1..6
$test | Foreach-Object { [PSCustomObject]@{Number=$_} }
```

You can save this back to a variable:

```
$test = 1..6
$testObjects = $test | Foreach-Object { [PSCustomObject]@{Number=$_} }
```

If an object has four or fewer properties, it will be displayed as a table.

So you could also, say, make an object with two properties and still get headers.

```
$test = 1..6
$test | Foreach-Object { [PSCustomObject]@{Number=$_;NumberTimesTwo = $_ * 2} }
```

If you want to control how any object displays in PowerShell, you'll want to learn about writing formatters.  There's a module I make called [EZOut](https://github.com/StartAutomating/EZOut) that makes these a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

To offer an alternative to [Start-Automating's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73737662/45375):

You can use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

To turn a list of numbers into objects (`[pscustomobject]` instances) with a `.Number` property, whose [display formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51805771/45375) defaults to the tabular display you're looking for:

```bash
$objects = 
  1,2,3,4,5,6 | Select-Object @{ Name='Number'; Expression={ $_ } }
```

Outputting `$objects` yields:

```
Number
------
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
```

You can use the same technique for adding additional properties to (copies of) existing objects, filling them at the same time (builds on the `$objects` variable filled above):

```bash
# Values for the new property.
$nums = 6..1 # same as: 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
$i = @{ val = 0 } # Helper hashtable for indexing into $nums
$objects | Select-Object *, @{ Name='NewProperty'; Expression={ $nums[$i.val++] } }
```

Output:

```bash
Numbers NewProperty
------- -----------
      1           6
      2           5
      3           4
      4           3
      5           2
      6           1
```

If you want to add a property with `$null` values first and fill them later, use:

```bash
$objects | Select-Object *, NewProperty
```