# How to get a lengthy string environment variable in full?

Tags: json, powershell, environment-variables, system-administration

The command `gci env:ApiSecret | ConvertTo-Json` works to [return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39800481/262852) a long string, the API secret for Twitter, which is truncated without the pipe to JSON.

However, the JSON is rather spammy.

Is there a "goldilocks" way to get the lengthy string value without the extraneous details?

(Unfortunately, `gci env:` truncates the key)

Comment: are you SURE that it is actually truncated? the display system truncates the _display_ but not the actual value, so you are likely seeing a _display_ artifact. that is especially true since your `ConvertTo-Json` is seeing the whole thing. [*grin*]

Comment: Heh, yeah...well, umm...

Comment: looks like `BACON` demoed the idea nicely. it's worth keeping the "display system" and "actual value" concept in mind. [*grin*]

Comment: tl;dr: `$env:ApiSecret` or `Get-Item env:ApiSecret | Format-List` or `Get-Item env:ApiSecret | Format-Table -Wrap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` is for retrieving all or a subset of items from a container.  Note that it outputs an object with `Name` and `Value` properties (substituting `Path` as another lengthy environment variable value)...

```bsh
PS> gci env:Path

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Path                           C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDO...
```

`Get-Item` yields the same result...

```bsh
PS> gi env:Path

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Path                           C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDO...
```

Either way, the object retrieved is a `DictionaryEntry`...

```bsh
PS> gi env:Path | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Collections.DictionaryEntry

Name          MemberType    Definition
----          ----------    ----------
Name          AliasProperty Name = Key
Equals        Method        bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode   Method        int GetHashCode()
GetType       Method        type GetType()
ToString      Method        string ToString()
PSDrive       NoteProperty  PSDriveInfo PSDrive=Env
PSIsContainer NoteProperty  bool PSIsContainer=False
PSPath        NoteProperty  string PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Environment::path
PSProvider    NoteProperty  ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Environment
Key           Property      System.Object Key {get;set;}
Value         Property      System.Object Value {get;set;}
```

...and when you pipe that to `ConvertTo-Json` it will include all kinds of undesirable properties from that class.

In short, don't use `ConvertTo-Json` for this.  Since you know the exact item you want, just retrieve it directly [using variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables#displaying-environment-variables)...

```bsh
PS> $env:Path
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;...
```

Equivalent code using [the .NET API](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable) would be...

```bsh
PS> [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path')
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;...
```

If you really wanted to use a `Get-*Item` cmdlet you'd just need to specify that it's the `Value` property you want using property syntax...

```bsh
PS> (gi env:Path).Value
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;...
```

...or `Select-Object`...

```bsh
PS> gi env:Path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Value'
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;...
```

All of the above commands will output only a `[String]` containing the entirety of that environment variable value.  I inserted trailing ellipses since showing my entire `Path` value is not useful here; in practice, those commands will output the entire environment variable with no truncation.

Comment: this worked for me: `(gi Env:/ApiSecret).Value` but some of your commands crashed (Linux?).  Is there something like:  `(gi env:).Key-and-Value`?  Or would you have to put the result into an array, then pull the key and value out?  Perhaps not key, but just "name"

Comment: I just tested all of those commands on PowerShell 6 for Windows and they worked.  I'm not quite understanding if you want just the value of one variable, or the name and value of many of them, or what you're asking here?  Is `gci env:ApiSecret`, as shown, what you want?  Or you want name and value formatted together in one `String`, like `gci env: | % { "$($_.Name):""$($_.Value)""" }`?

Comment: that'll do it, the name and value.  thanks.   (I was just asking for the value as the question was asked.)

Comment: I see.  If you want just the value of all environment variables you can modify the last three code snippets to `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables().Values`, `(gci env:).Value`, and `gci env: | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Value'`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

**The simplest way to inspect the *value* of environment variables *in full* is to use  the 
`$env:<varName>` ([namespace variable notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036515/45375)) syntax**, which in your case means: `$env:ApiSecret` (if the variable name contains special characters, enclose everything after the `$` in `{...}`; e.g., `${env:ApiSecret(1)}`)

That way, environment-variable values (which are invariably *strings*) that are longer than your terminal's (console's) width simply continue on subsequent lines.

To demonstrate:

```
# Simulate a long value (200 chars.)
$env:ApiSecret = 'x' * 199 + '!'

# Output the long value
$env:ApiSecret
```

With an 80-char. wide terminal, you'd see output as follows:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx!
```

---

**If you do want to use `Get-Item`** (or `Get-ChildItem`, which acts the same in this case), you have two options:

```
# Format-List shows each property on its own line, 
# with values wrapping across multiple lines
Get-Item env:ApiSecret | Format-List

# Format-Table -Wrap causes values to wrap as well.
Get-Item env:ApiSecret | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement does not strip anything away. However, for console display purpose, it truncate the output that you view in the console.

If you assign the result to a variable or pipe to a file, nothing will be truncated.

Therefore, my assumption on your question is that you want to view the result in the console without the console truncating your stuff there.

For that, you could write the results to the host yourself.
Here's a simple example that do just that.

```
$envvars = gci env: 
$Max = ($envvars.name| Measure-Object -Property length -Maximum).Maximum + 3
$envvars | % {Write-Host $_.name.padright($Max,' ')  -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewline;Write-Host $_.value}
```

**Result** — As you can see, the **path**  variable value is no longer truncated.

[image]

Comment: I like the way you put the variables in an array