# Echo path not working on my Windows 11 instance

Tags: windows, powershell

When entering echo path on PowerShell on my Windows 11, nothing proper is showing up.
I recall Windows 10 shows all environmental path variables, but not anymore?

Comment: `$env:Path.Split([IO.Path]::PathSeparator)` or alternatively, `[Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables('%PATH%').Split([IO.Path]::PathSeparator)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ECHO %PATH%` returns the value of the `PATH` environment variable when run in cmd.exe, but not PowerShell.

The PowerShell command you're looking for is as follows:

```
$env:PATH
```

If you need to list all environment variables in PowerShell, use `gci env:`. The equivalent command for cmd.exe is `SET`.

Please see [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800481/display-all-environment-variables-from-a-running-powershell-script) for more information.

Thanks to @mklement0 for the clarification.

Comment: Thank you, you just saved my day and my environment!