# Unable to execute aliases defined in the .bashrc file in gitbash

Tags: windows, git-bash

I have added certain `aliases` in `.bashrc` file, that point to the windows location of the `start-server bat` files of `kafka` and `zookeeper`. However when I run those in the `gitbash` its saying `Command not found` error

Example if I have below alias in `.bashrc` file and I run the command `zoo` in `gitbash` it gives above error

```
alias zoo="D:/Tools/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin/windows/kafka-server-start.bat"
```

Comment: Bash doesn't run Windows batch files. Use a Windows command interpreter to run these.

Comment: Kafka doesn't run that well in windows, anyway. You might want to try WSL2 instead

Answer (score 1):

Gitbash only reads `.bash_profile` not `.bashrc`, either place aliases in `.bash_profile` or place these line on the top of your `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]
then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

also see:
[Git for Windows doesn't execute my .bashrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186840/git-for-windows-doesnt-execute-my-bashrc-file)

Answer (score 0):

If you make modifications to you .bashrc file, make sure to source the file right after that at the command prompt and check your permission in order to do it. :

$ source .bashrc

Set any permission to 755 (chmod 755) at the command prompt as well if you are still having difficulties. Usually scourcing should do it.