# how can I install oh-my-posh in git bash windows terminal

Tags: themes, oh-my-posh

I have installed it in `PowerShell and it worked`, how can I install `oh-my-posh in git bash`?
I Have installed oh-my-posh with `scoop` then I added this code to `.bashrc`:

`eval "$(oh-my-posh --init --shell bash --config ~/amro.omp.json)"`

but unfortunately didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `.bashrc` doesn't load, it's either not sourced (or the right one). A quick search reveals the following [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186840/git-for-windows-doesnt-execute-my-bashrc-file):

> OK, I found out the problem. Quite simply, the bash terminal used by the latest Git for Windows 2.5.0 (mintty) doesn't bother to read .bashrc - it reads .bash_profile. So you can set up your environment in .bash_profile and/or put this code at the start to read .bashrc:

```bash
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]
then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Secondly, the command needs to be tweaked to this:

```bash
eval "$(oh-my-posh init bash --config ~/amro.omp.json)"
```

Original answer [here](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/discussions/2718#discussioncomment-3493942).