# Git Bash not exiting while loop, while bash in ubuntu does

Tags: bash, ubuntu, git-bash, msys2

I got a `while` loop in a Bash script which looks something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

# do something with kubectl port-forward

while ! nc -vz localhost "$port" > /dev/null 2>&1 ; do
    # echo sleeping
    sleep 0.1
done

#access ressource on the port-forwarded website
```

which basically is supposed to be waiting until a `kubectl port-forward` command has succesfully started.

However, executing the script under Git Bash (I execute via `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 bash`) leads to an infinite loop, as it never exits the `while` loop. I installed ncap and the nc command `nc -vz localhost $port` works on its own fine. Executing with `-x` shows that it is looping over the `nc` command which is running successfully.

Executing the same script in Ubuntu WSL, it just works, exits the `while` loop as intended and continues.

Comment: Re "Any help is appreciated" - 1) do as the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs and "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.", 2) don't redirect it's stdout and stderr to `/dev/null` when trying to figure out why a command isn't doing what you want, 3) run your script with `set -x` enabled to see what it's doing (so far we don't know if it's stuck in 1 call to `nc` or looping calling `nc` repeatedly).

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry, I added some more information. shellcheck did not have problems with the while loop itself.

Comment: There should be nothing in bash which explains the differences, but most likely you are running different `nc` executables. Do a `which nc` (and for the safe side a `which sleep`) before entering the loop.

Comment: @A7exSchin shellcheck would definitely have a couple of problems with your code. Even after adding a shebang as you did now (which is still not a valid shebang btw) it'd still complain  about the missing quotes around your variable. Posting code that even shellcheck can find problems in makes it harder for us to help you as then we need to walk you through those first. Running shellcheck was just the first suggestion I offered, did you try the other 2 too? What was the result ([edit] your question to show it).

Comment: When I copy/paste your current code into shellcheck it tells me: `Line 1:
#/bin/bash
 ^-- SC1113 (error): Use #!, not just #, for the shebang.
 
Line 5:
while ! nc -vz localhost $port > /dev/null 2>&1 ; do
                         ^-- SC2154 (warning): port is referenced but not assigned.
                         ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
while ! nc -vz localhost "$port" > /dev/null 2>&1 ; do
` - thats 2 errors we shouldnt have to consider, just fix them and any others til shellcheck is clean

Comment: Sorry again, I was too hasty editing and made a typo with the shebang. However, I figured out the issue and will post an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

So after some debugging using `bash -x` and removing the output to `/dev/null` it became apparent that while `nc` was available in my bash, starting the script via `bash script.sh` starts a new shell, which does not load the alias I set in my `~/.bashrc` which was `alias nc='ncap'`.

This was obfuscated due to the Git Bash not loading the `.bashrc` by default, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186840/git-for-windows-doesnt-execute-my-bashrc-file) and the fact that I was debugging the command by using `bash -x` before, but did not know that piping a commands output to `/dev/null` does also not show it in the debugging output. So in the end it just showed

```
nc -vz localhost 8002
sleep 0.1
```

in a loop, which I suspected to be a successful execution.