# .bashrc is not being read by git bash for git 2.5.1

Tags: git, bash, windows-10

I use `git for windows` for version controlling. Here is the code of my `.bashrc` file for initial setup:

```
#eval `ssh-agent`
#ssh-add

SSH_ENV=$HOME/.ssh/environment

# start the ssh-agent
function start_agent {
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
    # spawn ssh-agent
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add
}

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi

# aliases
alias serve='php artisan serve'
...
```

Today I upgraded to git version 2.5.1. Now the bash shell has stopped initializing the .bashrc on startup. Before upgrading `git-bash` was working perfectly and used to read the `bashrc` file on startup. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What configuration? Are you sure your `.bashrc` still exists and is being loaded? Did some other configuration file (that loaded your `.bashrc` change)?

Comment: I am bit surprised to see windows 10 using bash shell ?

Comment: It's the git for windows which uses bash shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also the possibility to edit `.bash_profile` so that it reads the contents of `.bashrc` like shown by this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32353083/1029261).

Answer (score 3):

Rename the `.bashrc` file to `.bash_profile`. This is the default config file for git 2.5.0 and later.