# Location of .bashrc for "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" in Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Microsoft just introduced a Linux subsystem in its Windows 10 Anniversary Edition. The installation is pretty straight forward, but I could not locate bash files on Windows.

How does it work? What does `~` refer to in Windows? Where to find `.bashrc`?

Comment: Just a note: make sure to use Linux line breaks when editing `.bashrc`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Since the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, the location changed to:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\{DIST}\LocalState\rootfs\home\{LINUXUSER}\
```

Where:

- `{DIST}` is equal to `CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc`
- `{LINUXUSER}` is the user for which you are looking for the .bashrc file

Just for anyone wondering that came here from Google.

Comment: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\{DIST}\LocalState\rootfs\home\` This folder seems to be empty

Comment: @quantumbutterfly It should be located there if you've installed it after the Fall Creators Update. If you installed it prior to that, it might still be in whatever folder it was back then.

Comment: It wasn't there even on the Fall Creators update, but I solved it by creating a new linux user using bash

Answer (score 30):

Sorry for the misunderstanding, I check on google and it will be at `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Lxss\home\USERNAME` .

I tried and it works, in the cmd just type `cd\ && dir *bashrc* /s` it will locate the file, and in my case i see the line `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Lxss\home\USERNAME` but when I want to navigate it with the window browser it doesn't work, but if you copy paste it, it works :-)

I found it [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/261383/how-to-access-your-ubuntu-bash-files-in-windows-and-your-windows-system-drive-in-bash/).

---

Considering that you need to know where a file is located you can use the `find` command. 
The syntax of the command is `find {search-path} {file-names-to-search} {action-to-take}`by default the action to take is printing the file name. 
So if you are finding .bashrc file you can use `find / -name .bashrc` the bash will return you `/home/yourusername/.bashrc`

Also, if you want to access to your home directory you can use `cd ~`

Hope my answer will be helpful :-)

Comment: sorry for the -1, I am new to this site. On my pc the path is "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\**lxss**\home\USERNAME" and not "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\**Lxss**\home\USERNAME"

Comment: My reputation is too low to affect publicly displayed score. Maybe your answer was downvoted by someone else. I already gave you a +1.
Also, the command you gave didn't work for me. It gets stuck after searching some directories and shows lots of "Permission denied" errors.

Comment: Ho ok no problem :)

Comment: @MeetTaraviya: The Windows shells (cmd.exe, PowerShell) and the Windows API are _case-insensitive_ with respect to the filesystem, so the case difference you point to makes no practical difference.

Comment: First of all, do not change Linux files using Windows (as explained here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/). If you really want to find the file, check in "File Explorer Options -> Show hidden files, folders and drives" path is not hidden and also consider that "Lxss" is extra hidden.

Comment: "So windows files can't be accessed from within bash." I realise this is off topic in the context of your question, but for anyone reading this at a later date, you can access Windows files within WSL. For example, the contents of your C drive should be found under /mnt/c .

Answer (score 7):

~ means that is user home folder, way like /home/%username%/

you can list files like `ls -al` and see .bashrc file.

Comment: please see my comment on answer by BinaryDump

Answer (score 7):

just type
`vi ~/.bashrc`

and that should put you into the file where ever it is.
You can navigate there simply by doing `cd ~`
List all files with `ls -a` and you should be able to see it.

Comment: If you've ever used git bash, you will probably have a different .bashrc file in whatever was the directory where that shell would start up. However, once you begin using wsl, ubuntu's .bashrc file will be in a different location, much closer to the true root. Hence you need to use `~` to get to ubuntu's home directory

Answer (score 2):

Right now on WSL 2 you can find it under `/home/{user_name}` and the file is hidden.

You can access it from Ubuntu console by `{text_editor} .bashrc`

If you want to edit that in Windows just type in ubuntu console `explorer.exe .` and it opens the current folder and shows all hidden files.
It's weird but works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers doesn't work for me using WSL 2.

The `LocalState` folder contains a virtual disk so `rootfs` does not exist,

and `AppData\Local` folder does not have the `Lxss` folder.

The solution for me is surprisingly simple:

```sh
wsl -u root
```

This will allow you to get into `wsl` as `root`.

From here, you have access to the whole linux.
Fix the `.bashrc` or anything you want.

Don't screw up the `root` user. :)

Answer (score 0):

I find my `.bashrc` file in:

```
/home/your_user_name
```

you can run `cd /home/your_user_name` or `cd ~` should work as well

If you previously installed git bash for window, you may also find `.bashrc` file in your window user profile folder. In Linux subsystem, you may local the file under `/mnt/c/Users/your_window_user_name/.bashrc` However, modifying that file only works for git bash in window but not for the shell terminal of the Linux subsystem.

Note: my installation of the Ubuntu is 20.04 LTS straight from window store.