# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on bash on Ubuntu windows

Tags: bash, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am able to install docker, docker-compose and docker-machine

However when I try to run

```
root@DESKTOP-51NFMIM:~# docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Is there any suggestion for solving this problem?

Comment: Are you sure *Docker is running*?

Comment: Yes, When I run docker --version its return the version
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

Comment: Did you try running systemctl restart docker?

Comment: Do you use WSL or WSL2?

Comment: For connecting to local Docker for Windows from WSL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516777/is-docker-running-within-wsl-or-connecting-back-to-windows

Comment: https://blog.jayway.com/2017/04/19/running-docker-on-bash-on-windows/

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Found the solution on this post: https://blog.jayway.com/2017/04/19/running-docker-on-bash-on-windows/

Running docker against an engine on a different machine is actually quite easy, as Docker can expose a TCP endpoint which the CLI can attach to.

This TCP endpoint is turned off by default; to activate it, right-click the Docker icon in your taskbar and choose Settings, and tick the box next to “Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS”.

With that done, all we need to do is instruct the CLI under Bash to connect to the engine running under Windows instead of to the non-existing engine running under Bash, like this:

```
$ docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 images
```

There are two ways to make this permanent – either add an alias for the above command or export an environment variable which instructs Docker where to find the host engine (NOTE: make sure to use single apostrophe's below):

```
$ echo "export DOCKER_HOST='tcp://0.0.0.0:2375'" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Now, running docker commands from Bash works just like they’re supposed to.

```
$ docker run hello-world
```

Successful response:

```
Hello from Docker!This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

Comment: 50 useless StackOverflow "answers" later and this one actually solves my problem. Didn't know that setting in the docker windows app was even there. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: thanks @AgmLauncher .. maybe OP can mark it as answer :)

Comment: Thank you @RamiSarieddine for the answer!    What I finally understood is that the Docker Engine does not run on WSL, you need to have Docker For Windows installed. I ended up having **Docker client running on Linux (WSL)** sending commands to **Docker Engine daemon installed on Windows**.

Comment: Are you saying that Docker Desktop must be installed on Windows 10 before docker commands will work in Ubuntu-on-windows? I just went through all the steps here `https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/` ... to install docker on ubuntu subsystem...so I assumed it was there. There is no "docker icon in my taskbar" because I didn't install it on windows.

Comment: Hmm, no change for me... (Windows 10x64, WSL2)

Answer (score 31):

The Docker client and server can now be installed and run purely in WSL without Docker Desktop for Windows if you are running Windows 10 version 1803 or greater. I have it working on the following WSL:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic [Ubuntu on Windows 10]
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft
```

Simply follow the same [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) to install on Ubuntu but make sure to choose a specific version to install. Presently, version *18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu* works fine but later versions up to *5:18.09.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic* have an issue with starting up a container. The following command will install the latest working version:

```
apt-get install docker-ce=18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu
```

To get the Docker server running in WSL after installation, close all open terminals and start a new Ubuntu terminal as administrator (i.e., right click the Ubuntu shortcut and click 'Run as administrator'). Finally, run the following commands:

```
sudo cgroupfs-mount
sudo service docker start
```

`sudo service docker start` will have to be run each time Windows is rebooted. However, if you wish to avoid that, you can automate it using the Task Scheduler and a shell script by following the steps listed [here](https://medium.com/faun/docker-running-seamlessly-in-windows-subsystem-linux-6ef8412377aa).

Test that everything is working using:

```
docker run hello-world
```

Reference:
https://medium.com/faun/docker-running-seamlessly-in-windows-subsystem-linux-6ef8412377aa

Comment: Just tried this whole process today - does not work, I get the "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://0.0.0.0:2375. Is the docker daemon running?" error

Comment: I get the same issue as @kpollock, all these articles online mention most of the same steps, but when setting Docker for Desktop to expose its daemon, it just doesn't work from inside WSL, it can't connect to it no matter what I try.

Comment: Funnily enough, if I set the environment variable while running the command it works, but if it's in my `.bashrc` it doesn't.

e.g. this works for me

`DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375 docker info`

Comment: @kpollock I would suggest trying to reinstall your Ubuntu WSL and start the process completely fresh. Ensure that you are running the latest Windows 10 version (I am on 1809) which will enable using _cgroups_. It is also important that the commands are run in a terminal with elevated permissions. I was able to get it running on another system running Windows 10 version 1809 without Docker Desktop for Windows installed.

Comment: Even after sourcing the bash modification and checking the box in windows, I had to manually right click and restart the docker service for the hello-world to run.

Comment: This worked for me with one additional step. After installing Docker on Linux, I needed to clear the `DOCKER_HOST` environmental variable with `export DOCKER_HOST=`. After that I was able to successfully connect to the Linux daemon e.g. with `sudo docker system info`. After that I no longer needed Docker Desktop for Windows.

Comment: Today I'm able to install and run **latest docker version completely inside WSL 2**. I just need to start docker manually `sudo service docker start`.

Answer (score 13):

for me this worked for WSL for windows:

- 1> go to: Turn Windows features on or off
- 2> deselect "Hyper-V", restart,
- 3> go to "Turn Windows features on or off" again,
- 4> select "Hyper-V" again
- and restart a last time. Afterwards docker was reachable again.

assuming you have installed docker desktop for windows and
Settings->General->Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS is ticked

Comment: Thanks you very much, it just did it

Answer (score 7):

Note: if you are using the Ubuntu from [WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), do understand that the docker client is working, not the docker server (daemon).

See [Microsoft/WSL issue 2114](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2114) and [this thread](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13250370-docker).

For the server, you would still need to use only [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) and its Hyper-V VM.

Then, [Microsoft/WSL issue 2102](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2102#issuecomment-305656136) adds:

> I was able to make TLS work from inside WSL by changing `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` environment variable (which I got from running `eval $(docker-machine.exe env --shell bash)`) from "`C:\C:\Users\mmarchini\.docker\machine\machines\default`" to "`/mnt/c/Users/mmarchini/.docker/machine/machines/default/`" .
>   At least docker build seems to be working now, I'll try using `docker-compose` later.

See [this script](https://gist.github.com/mmarchini/bc9df7b82127fea13612edf8bffdf96f) (from [Matheus Marchini](https://github.com/mmarchini)) to launch a docker-machine bash with the right setting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import run, PIPE

completed_process = run(["docker-machine.exe", "env", "--shell", "bash"], stdout=PIPE)

docker_env = completed_process.stdout.decode("ascii")

for line in docker_env.split("\n"):
    if "DOCKER_CERT_PATH" in line:
        env_var, path, _ = line.split('"')
        path = path.replace("\\", "/")
        drive, path = path.split(":", 1)
        path = "/mnt/{}{}".format(drive.lower(), path)
        line = '{}"{}"'.format(env_var, path)
print(line)
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2527, but I believe the Docker API available on :2375 is not secure so is turned off by default.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, took me so many hours to figure it, I realized that running `docker ps` without root privileges gives this error, If any one else is experiencing the same you could try `sudo docker ps` it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

**DO NOT USER OTHER METHODS IN LATEST DOCKER DESKTOP**

I had the same "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon" issue when trying to use docker inside WSL2.

I believe this has made been simpler in latest version of Docker Desktop.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers

- Update to latest (Mine is Docker Desktop 4.3.2 (72729))

  - May work in an earlier version, haven't checked when exactly the feature was made available.
- Enable WSL 2 based engine: `Settings > General > Use the WSL 2 based engine`
- Enable WSL integration in `Settings > Resources > WSL Integration`
  (attaching a pic, as the menu settings may change for different versions)

  - NOTE: strangely, even though my default WSL distro was Ubuntu, I had to explicitly enable it for Ubuntu for it to work
  - may need to restart Docker Desktop
  - I also did NOT need to turn on "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" for it to work
- NOTE: I initially attempted the old method of adding the 3 env variables as suggested in other [posts](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/03/02/docker-in-wsl2).

  - However, using the latest Docker Desktop, this wasn't necessary, and removed the 3 variables from `.bashrc`

  ```
  $ echo >> ~/.bashrc <<EOF
  # Connect to Docker on Windows
  export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/mnt/c/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/.docker/machine/certs
  export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
  export DOCKER_HOST='tcp://0.0.0.0:2375'
  EOF
  $ source ~/.bashrc
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is mostly correct. However, I wanted to specify that when using WSL2 + Docker Desktop:

- You must unset DOCKER_HOST which was previously needed in WSL1

  - Mine was defined in `~/.bashrc` in both Windows and WSL.
  - Delete in both. Also delete in Windows env variables via Control Panel.
  - Check with `env | grep -i docker` to make sure it's gone.
- You must also set the correct settings in Docker Desktop

  - Uncheck `Export daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS`
  - Check `Use the WSL2 based engine`
  - Resources -> WSL Integration -> Check `Enable integration with my default WSL distro`

Now, you can do a simple `docker info` to check if you're running the same server version in WSL and in Windows (Powershell).

Comment: Deleting "DOCKER_HOST" from .bashrc worked for me. I didn't had to do other steps though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker desktop for windows (and do not require TLS for the connection) then go to the docker desktop setting, general section and enabled the checkbox "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS".

Update: in newer Docker desktop versions the WSL integration has moved to the resources section.

Answer (score 1):

Running WSL2 and WSL 2 based engine (not Hyper-V)

For some reason this toggle button under "Resources" -> "WSL Integration" was turned off. The moment I turned it on again everything worked as expected.

Make sure it is turned on for you before digging any deeper.

I assume I haven't set my Ubuntu distro as my default distro so the checkbox wasn't doing anything.

[image: Resources panel]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was already said, I would like to share with you some issues that I had while setting up and the solutions that eventually allowed me to start working with a WSL2/Docker Desktop combo.
This is not a complete guide, just another source of troubleshooting!

### My goal was

1. Start Experimenting with Docker.
2. Setup my environment so it is as recommended and most comfortable.
3. Basically to be able to work in a Linux Context while working with Docker Desktop.

### How I went about it

1. I upgraded my PC from Win 10 Home to Win 10 Pro, to avoid various issues I read that people were having with the Home edition.
2. I had Docker Toolbox installed and then deleted it as well as the Oracle VM install I had on my PC. I had various small issues, read online that it's best to remove Oracle VM as well.
3. I installed Docker Desktop.

### Issues and their solutions

  1. A few of the environment variables from the old Docker Tools installation remained.
  This caused Docker Desktop to misbehave.
  Solution: I deleted all of them. (Any variable name that mentioned Docker)

  2. When trying to connect to Docker on localhost:2375 via Ubuntu WSL2 got the famous "...is docker even running" error.
  Worth mentioning that on cmd docker was working properly at this stage.
  Solution:
    - Purge a previous installation of Docker I had on my Ubuntu WSL2.
    - Make sure to delete all and any environment variables that mentioned Docker on my ubuntu WSL2.
    - Stop Hyper-v, Rebooted, Started Hyper-V Rebooted on Windows.
    - Install the latest version of Docker via `apt-get`.

Now running on Ubuntu WSL2 "docker context ls" to check my setup should result in:

```
NAME        DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT               KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default *   Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                         swarm
```

Running Docker Info from Ubuntu WSL2:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.0-docker)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.5.0)

Server:
 Containers: 3
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 3
 Images: 3...
```

Answer (score 0):

Exposing your Docker Host should follow these steps:

#1. create the following directory if it doesn't exist

`sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`

#2. create `options.conf` configuration file with the following content

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/options.conf`

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

#3. reload the `systemd` daemon

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

#4. restart docker

`sudo systemctl restart docker`

If you want to have an encrypted connection, then you should replace port 2375 with 2376, and set up `certificates` and `daemon.json` configuration files in `/etc/docker/certs/` and `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. Example:

```
{
    "tlsverify": true,
    "tlscacert": "/etc/docker/certs/ca-cert.pem",
    "tlscert": "/etc/docker/certs/server-cert.pem",
    "tlskey": "/etc/docker/certs/server-key.pem",
    "host": "tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

only needs add a env variable in your system

[image]