# Docker not reachable on Arch Linux

Tags: docker, archlinux, antergos

I have researched this issue extensively to no avail, and also asked on unix.stackexchange.com also to no avail, so I'm asking here in hopes someone else has some insight into why this is occurring, as asking on both the unix board as well as github has shed no insight whatsoever.

I cannot get Docker to play nice on Antergos, or be reachable without `sudo`. Running container builds with `sudo` causes a number of issues, such as ssh keys not being detected and nginx not being recognized. This problem arose about 3 days ago, and rolling back has not made any difference. Uninstalling docker completely and reinstalling also did not make any difference. Neither has updating my configuration, permissions, or any other available setting.

System version: `4.17.8-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 18 09:56:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
Current docker version: `18.04.0-ce` (also tried on all versions up to current `18.05` to no avail, have rolled back one version at a time with no effect).

Existing research led to the typical issue being that [the user needs to be in the docker group](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) to circumvent `sudo`, however I am, and it is still not working. I have also checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047810/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-on-bash-on-ubuntu-windows), [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-running-on-this-host/8925/10), and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252684/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-when-the-daemon-is-runnin), and all of them offer the same (not working) answer.

**Please do not suggest checking my user group or adding my user to the docker group, as this is not the issue, as outlined below.**

Everything worked fine until a couple of days ago. I am inclined to believe an automatic update broke it.

Below is some context:

Output of `groups`

```
root http docker users wheel
```

When calling any docker command without sudo (eg `docker info`, `docker ps`, `docker run ...` `docker-compose up`, etc), I get the following:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

It is definitely running. `systemctl status docker` yeilds the following:

```
    ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-07-20 14:52:54 EDT; 21min ago
 Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 472 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 50 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 139.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─ 472 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
           ├─ 620 docker-containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml
           ├─ 802 docker-containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/e0942c95c35608cecbbe761d27a2c5386d9faec072cf8031>
           ├─ 818 bash -c echo "RESTARTING GUlP COMMAND" && npm rebuild node-sass && npm upgrade && npm update && npm install && gulp && tail -f /dev/null
           └─1572 tail -f /dev/null
```

It is likewise displayed when running `htop` and `ps aux | grep docker`.

perms for `ls -la $(which docker)`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root docker 36823912 Apr 17 18:48 /usr/bin/docker
```

According to this, it should absolutely be accessible without sudo, but still chokes on all commands without sudo. I cannot just run it with sudo due to a number of production build scripts that require user space locality failing, which break when sudo is applied.

output of `sudo docker info`

```
Containers: 15
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 14
Images: 30
Server Version: 18.04.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk 
syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.17.8-1-ARCH
Operating System: Antergos Linux
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 31.02GiB
Name: Indibog
ID: OCC4:P3QN:B5EU:J2Y4:LZN4:WAIC:2F5V:ZQZD:NLXY:DWVE:X2LB:TLEQ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 27
 Goroutines: 39
 System Time: 2018-07-20T15:04:01.745176194-04:00
 EventsListeners: 0
Username: mopsyd
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 192.168.40.60:5000
 sandbox.cdp.local:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: I think the archlinux forums are the best place to ask. This is definitely not a programming question

Comment: Is the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable set?  The `tcp://localhost:2375` value you quote isn't a default (and if it ever worked it was extremely dangerous).

Comment: It is. I have unset it, but it gets reset whenever I open any other shell window. Docker commands work only within the same window after unsetting it. Seems to be set by the system somewhere in the individual shell process.