# How do I make custom git commands?

Tags: git, command, git-bash

In the past I was able to edit a file and add a custom command of mine. I believe I did something like this:

```
acp($1, $2){
     git add .
     git commit -m $1
     git push origin $2
}
```

I know there are aliases but I am not looking to shorten my commands I am looking for a way to edit a file where I can put my own custom git command in.

Comment: You can create a `.bashrc` file and add aliases there. If using Windows, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6883760/5987698).

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html