# How to customize git bash shell configuration on Windows

Tags: windows, git-bash

I have Git Bash on Windows and want to customize things with dotfiles. I'm new to all of this so thank you for any help and patience.

I am trying to follow the answers from [Git for Windows: .bashrc or equivalent configuration files for Git Bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883760/git-for-windows-bashrc-or-equivalent-configuration-files-for-git-bash-shell), but I think they are outdated with respect to the default install folder/file structure; for example, I can't find any `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files (except for the Shell file in screenshot below, maybe that is it?). I think the pertinent files are in `profile.d` I have git version 2.36.0.windows.1

An example entry in the `.alias` file might be something like `alias mydir='C:/Users/name/Documents'`, and I'd like to be able to type `cd mydir` into the Git Bash prompt.

This is what the installed folder looks like:

[image]

And this is what the `~/profile.d` folder looks like:

[image]

Open to recommendations, but after researching, I think I want to set up a folder called ".dotfiles" with a text file called ".alias" and another text file called ".functions" (i.e., `~/.dotfiles/.alias` and `~/.dotfiles/.function`). I want to have these as separate files rather than editing the text files from the installation in `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d`.

I have two questions on this:

1. Where should the `~/.dotfiles` folder be located? In `C:\Program Files\Git`?
2. How do I add/activate all of the text files in my `~/.dotfiles` folder automatically in every session? I don't understand the syntax nor where this would go (maybe in `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\bash_profile.sh`?)

**EDIT** This is the content of `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\bash_profile.sh`:

```
# add ~/.bash_profile if needed for executing ~/.bashrc
if [ -e ~/.bashrc -a ! -e ~/.bash_profile -a ! -e ~/.bash_login -a ! -e ~/.profile ]; then
  printf "\n\033[31mWARNING: Found ~/.bashrc but no ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile.\033[m\n\n"
  echo "This looks like an incorrect setup."
  echo "A ~/.bash_profile that loads ~/.bashrc will be created for you."
  cat >~/.bash_profile <<-\EOF
    # generated by Git for Windows
    test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
    test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
    EOF
fi
```

Comment: ~, or your home directory, is `C:/Users/yourusername/`, so create/edit your .bashrc there

Comment: Don't think of git-bash as having anything to do with Git, because it doesn't. It's just *included with* Git-for-Windows because Git needs bash (well, any shell, but bash was there).

Comment: @torek definitely! Git Bash is just my way of using Bash on Windows b/c I have to use Windows for work. I don't like Windows command line or PowerShell, but I like Bash and want to set up customizations (functions, etc.) to be more efficient. Is there a better way (not Git Bash) to get Bash on Windows?

Comment: There are multiple bash ports. I've only personally used the one that came with Cygwin, back when I was forced to use Windows for a bit and had a (work provided) machine with Cygwin installed. I have no idea which one is best (if there is even a linear way to rank goodness in the first place).

Comment: (My vague understanding is that there are two competing ecosystems, msys2 and mingw64, at this point. Apparently they don't work very well with each other, some kind of bad library / DLL-hell thing or something.)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this was the case, as my `MINGW64` based Bash shell was started by an external windows app, and in a funny way, it was dumping me into a different directory.

The only way out was to do `cd ~; pwd` and put your `.bashrc` in there.

If that still doesn't work, try looking for changes in the `.bash_history` file.
To find it, use:

```bash
cd /c/
find ./ -iname ".bash_history" 2>/dev/null
```