# Python arg is altered when using vscode git bash terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

vscode seems to be altering an argument passed into a python script. Below is the script. Note this only happens when running in the vscode git bash terminal (powershell terminal has no issues).

```
import argparse
parser.add_argument("--path")
args=parser.parse_args()
print(args.path)
```

```
$ python test.py --path /some/folder

C:/Users/defaultuser/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/some/folder
```

The expected output would be `/some/folder`

Note passing in `'some/folder'` outputs `'some/folder'`... very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not specific to vscode. The issue also occurs when executing in the Git Bash terminal directly.
This behavior would be true for any MSYS (short for "Minimal SYStem" a collection of GNU utilities, such as bash, make, and others, intended to provide a POSIX-compliant environment on Windows operating systems )
You can get past this issue by setting

```
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
```

or by using // at the starting of the path

```
$ python test.py --path //some/folder

//some/folder
```

both of these solutions are discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250130/how-to-stop-mingw-and-msys-from-mangling-path-names-given-at-the-command-line/7252767#7252767)

Comment: Thank you that works but how do I make that setting permanent?

Comment: To make the setting permanent  add `export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` to the `.bashrc` file for git. This would automatically set this parameter each time you launch git bash. Detailed steps to do so is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883760/git-for-windows-bashrc-or-equivalent-configuration-files-for-git-bash-shell)